# Pass / Get multiple Enum values in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums, enum-flags

Pass value which is the combination of enum values and get the corresponding enum strings of it.

Here is my scenario,

```
enum EnumDays {
    NONE = 0,
    SUN = 1,
    MON = 2,
    TUE = 4,
    WED = 8,
    THU = 16,
    FRI = 32,
    SAT = 64,
    ALL = 127
}
```

I'll pass the value as 5, which is the combination of SUN & TUE (1 + 4 = 5).

I want to get "SUN" & "TUE" as result. How to achieve this?

Comment: You need to use bitwise operators. `EnumDays.SUN|EnumDays.TUE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done either by iterating through bits or by iterating through enum members.  Iterating through bits seems a little cleaner.  We take advantage of the fact that `EnumDays` maps values to keys (e.g., `1` to `SUN`) as well as keys to values (`SUN` to `1`).  (Nit: This approach won't find an enum value of `2147483648`.  `1 << 31`, which is `-2147483648`, will work.)

```
function getDayNames(value: EnumDays) {
    let names = [];
    for (let bit = 1; bit != 0; bit <<= 1) { 
        if ((value & bit) != 0 && bit in EnumDays) { 
            names.push(EnumDays[bit]);
        }
    }
    return names;
}
```