# Enums in Typescript with use in functions

Tags: typescript, types, enums

I am just a beginner in Typescript and I am going over a practice assessment question about Enums in Typescript.  I am totally confused with this question:

> Extend the Permission enum so that it has the following fields:

> Read, which should have a value of 1

> Write, which should have a value of 2

> Execute, which should have a value of 4

> Extend the getPermissionList function so that it accepts a combination of several Permission enums and returns an array of strings which are the names of the Permissions.
>
> For example, executing:
>
> getPermissionList(Permission.Read | Permission.Write); should return [
> 'Read', 'Write' ] in any order.

So far I have something like this but I don't know if am in the ballpark:

```
function getPermissionList(permission: Permission): string[] {
     let arr: string[]
     for (let enumMember in permission) {
        arr.push(enumMember);
    }
    return arr;
}

enum Permission {
    Read = 1,
    Write = 2,
    Execute = 4,
    
}

//console.log(getPermissionList(Permission.Read | Permission.Write));
```

I know it isn't right as I am getting errors but I feel like im banging my head against a wall right now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass / Get multiple Enum values in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765150/pass-get-multiple-enum-values-in-typescript)

Comment: It doesn't solve it because that one just takes the full Enum and filters it in, if you look at the question they asked me, it is a function that takes two parameters:

getPermissionList(Permission.Read | Permission.Write); should return [ 'Read', 'Write' ] in any order.

Comment: `Permission.Read | Permission.Write` is not _two_ parameters. It's a binary OR of two enum values, as in the linked question. Please check that one and compare with your case; the only major difference I can see is that enum keys are not extracted there.

Comment: I know it is the OR, however the expected solution to having the OR in the function produces a result of " should return [ 'Read', 'Write' ]".  While it is the OR, it still produces a result with an array with BOTH Read and Write

Comment: Are you a beginner in JavaScript as well or just TypeScript?  If you know JavaScript, then `Permission` is just an object that looks like `{Read: 1, Write: 2, Execute: 4, "1": "Read", "2": "Write", "4": "Execute"}`.  So you will need to do bitwise arithmetic on `permission` and then use the set bits to pull keys or values out of the `Permission` object.  You could maybe do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/mpgnXN) but there's lots of ways to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

This involves taking advantage of bitwise arithmetic for enums. You can learn more about them here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html.
For this question, it seems like your input for your enum values are only numbers, so we can use the bitwise & operator to compare permission with the possible enum types for Permission. The following is a brittle solution showcasing this concept:

```
function getPermissionList(permission: Permission): string[] {

  let arr: string[] = []
  if(permission & Permission.Read) {
    arr.push( Permission[Permission.Read] )
  }

  if(permission & Permission.Write) {
    arr.push( Permission[Permission.Write] )
  }

  if(permission & Permission.Execute) {
    arr.push( Permission[Permission.Execute] )
  }

  return arr;

}
```

Another approach that loops through an enum's names and does the above may look like this:

```
function getPermissionList(permission: Permission): string[] {
  let arr: string[] = []
  for (var key  in Permission) {
    if (isNaN(Number(key)) ) { //skips over value : key definitions which assumes values are numbers
       if( permission & Permission[key as keyof typeof Permission] ) {
         let enumName = Permission[ Permission[key as keyof typeof Permission] ]
         arr.push( enumName )
       } 
    }    
  }
  return arr;
}
```

I hope this helps and as an exercise, I would recommend figuring out how to solve this problem with string enums :)